# Garbage Values Inside QtableView

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I have 4 QtableViews with 4 rows and 4 columns.However, The cells are filled with garbage values and the application is terminated whenever the value in cell is edited .
Sample code,

```
QTableView* const calibrationViews[H20_Num_Ranges]=
                              {calibration_ui->CalibrationView1,
                               calibration_ui->CalibrationView2,
                               calibration_ui->CalibrationView3,
                               calibration_ui->CalibrationView4
                              };


            calibrationViews[i]->resizeColumnToContents(0);
            calibrationViews[i]->resizeColumnToContents(1);
            calibrationViews[i]->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
            connect(_calibrationModels[i],
                     SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
                     this, SLOT(ProcessGUICalibrationChange()));
QModelIndex gainIndex = _calibrationModels[0]->index(0,
                                    H20CalibrationModel::GainColumn);
        newVal = gainIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString().toFloat(&ok);
        if (!qFuzzyCompare(calibration.probe[0].temperatureAdcGain,
                           newVal))
        {
            calibration.probe[0].temperatureAdcGain= newVal;
            calibrationChanged = true;
        }
        // Offset
        QModelIndex offsetIndex = _calibrationModels[0]->index(0,
                                    H20CalibrationModel::OffsetColumn);
        newVal = offsetIndex.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString().toFloat(&ok);
        if (!qFuzzyCompare(calibration.probe[0].temperaturAdcOffset,
                           newVal))
        {
            calibration.probe[0].temperaturAdcOffset = newVal;
            calibrationChanged = true;
        }
```

Please Help

Comment: Sound like a possible crash. Please run your program in a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: I degugged it , but it just puts some random value.How to remove all the garbage values to initial value of 0 and make the cell editable ?

Comment: And where did it crash? As for your garbage values, you probably make the contents point to something that later goes out of scope (like returning pointer or reference to a local variable).

Comment: The program crashes if I start editing the cell in any of the views.

Comment: Yes, and? The debugger is there to help you find *where in the code* that crash happens. Learn to use the debugger, it's most valuable tool for a programmer after the compiler. And do look over how you initialize the fields, so you don't use possible invalid pointers/references.

Comment: When I am trying to edit the cells, its still reseting to the garbage values.